# Creating a boolean for hangman game. STUCK

Tags: java, boolean

I'm new to java and I'm trying to create a basic hangman game, i've created methods for the round, but I got stuck with creating a boolean value that will turn the game to the next round (player loses one attempt to guess a letter if he puts wrong letter; he can be mistaken only 10 times; if guesses, he simply continues game).
There's my code so far, I tried even exclude boolean by if/else statement, but it seems very dumb to me. Any help will be useful. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignmenTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        welcomeMessage();
        String myWord = randomizeWord();
        char[] hiddenWord = hideWord(myWord);
        printArr(hiddenWord);
        char guess = userLine();
        game(guess, myWord);
        //
        // indexOfGuessed(guess,myWord,hiddenWord);
        // printArr(hiddenWord);
    }

    public static void game (char userGuess, String word) {
        int attempts = 10;
        while (attempts > 0) {
            round();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (userGuess != word.charAt(i)) {
                    attempts--;
                    System.out.println("You have"+attempts+"attempts. Try again!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void round () {
        String myWord = randomizeWord();
        char[] hiddenWord = hideWord(myWord);
        printArr(hiddenWord);
        char guess = userLine();

        indexOfGuessed(guess,myWord,hiddenWord);
        printArr(hiddenWord);
        return;
    }


    public static void welcomeMessage() {
        String welcome = "Welcome";
        System.out.println(welcome);
    }// say hi

    public static String randomizeWord() {
        Random r = new Random();
        String[] dictionary = {"hello", "dear", "Universe"};
        int wordIndex = r.nextInt(dictionary.length);
        String myWord = dictionary[wordIndex];
        return myWord;
    }

    public static char[] hideWord(String myString) {
        char[] hidWord = new char[myString.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            hidWord[i] = '*';
        }
        return hidWord;
    }

    public static char userLine() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nYour word is above. Guess a letter!");
        char userInput = in.next().charAt(0);
        return userInput;
    }

    public static String stars(String word) {
        String stars = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            stars += '*';
        }
        return stars;
    }

    public static void  printArr (char [] arr) {
        System.out.println();
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void indexOfGuessed(char userGuess, String word, char[] hiddenWord) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (userGuess == word.charAt(i)) {
                hiddenWord[i] = userGuess;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other thing (as your question regarding boolean return value seems answered):
Everytime `round()` is called, you create a new `String myWord`.

This String is only visible to the `round()` method and not the same as the `String myWord` that you initialize in the main method.

I'd advise you to just make `myWord` a global variable, set once, and let the other methods reference this variable if needed.

As it is right now, every call to `round()` just gets you a NEW random word from your dictionary.

I`d also say you would be better of if you didn't make everything static just because eclipse (or some other IDE) told you you can't make non-static references in a static main method:

```
String myWord;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AssignmenTwo a2 = new AssignmenTwo();
        a2.runGame();
        //
        // indexOfGuessed(guess,myWord,hiddenWord);
        // printArr(hiddenWord);
    }

    public void runGame(){
        welcomeMessage();
        myWord = randomizeWord();
        char[] hiddenWord = hideWord(myWord);
        printArr(hiddenWord);
        char guess = userLine();
        game(guess, myWord);
    }

    public void game(char userGuess, String word) {
        int attempts = 10;
        while (attempts > 0) {
            round();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (userGuess != word.charAt(i)) {
                    attempts--;
                    System.out.println("You have" + attempts + "attempts. Try again!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void round() {

        char[] hiddenWord = hideWord(myWord);
        printArr(hiddenWord);
        char guess = userLine();

        indexOfGuessed(guess, myWord, hiddenWord);
        printArr(hiddenWord);
        return;
    }  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `IndexOfGuessed` function like this, so it will return the status of the search:

```
public static void findGuessed(char userGuess, String word, char[] hiddenWord) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (userGuess == word.charAt(i)) {
            hiddenWord[i] = userGuess;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Then you can make `round` also return a boolean which says if it's won or not:

```
public static void round () {
    String myWord = randomizeWord();
    char[] hiddenWord = hideWord(myWord);
    printArr(hiddenWord);
    char guess = userLine();

    return findGuessed(guess, myWord, hiddenWord);
}
```

Then in `game` you can check the round:

```
boolean won = round();
if (won) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it out.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch, if one of the answers helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and/or voting for it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
while (attempts > 0) {
    round();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (userGuess != word.charAt(i)) {
            attempts--;
            System.out.println("You have"+attempts+"attempts. Try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

You should make a unique loop with a boolean that defines if the game is over like :

```
boolean over = false;

while(!over){
    over = round();
}
```

Where `round()` would call functions that would capture the suggestion of the user, compare it to the secret word and decrement the value of `attempts` (which could either be an attribute of the class or a variable passed in the parameters) and return if the game is over after prompting the result to the user.

When leaving the loop, you could ask the user if they wish to try again and call a setup function to reinitiate the game.